# FormsAuthentication.RedirectToLoginPage Not Working When Application at Root of Site

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, c#-4.0, iis-7.5

The application (ASP.Net 4 / C#) I've been developing uses FormsAuthentication.RedirectToLoginPage() to send the user back to the login page after he/she has clicked on a Logout button.

I'm finding that when the application is deployed at the root of a IIS Site, the redirect does not work. Clicking on the logout button simply reloads the page.

When the application is deployed to an Application virtual folder within the site, the redirect works property.

I've also tried using Respond.Redirect(), which also does not work. I've tried recreating the site from scratch (no luck).

UPDATE: I have been able to verify this behavior on another machine, so I'm pretty confident it's not just the one web server.

The code for the logout button:

```
    protected void lbLogout_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
        Session.Abandon();

        // clear authentication cookie
        HttpCookie cookie1 = new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, "");
        cookie1.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddYears(-1);
        cookie1.Path = FormsAuthentication.FormsCookiePath;
        cookie1.HttpOnly = true;
        Response.Cookies.Add(cookie1);

        // clear session cookie 
        HttpCookie cookie2 = new HttpCookie("ASP.NET_SessionId", "");
        cookie2.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddYears(-1);
        Response.Cookies.Add(cookie2);

        FormsAuthentication.RedirectToLoginPage();
        //Response.Redirect("~/login.aspx");
        Response.End();
    }
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: what is in the loginurl attribute in your web.config authentication>forms node?

Comment: @Hardrada: my web.config authentication and authorization block:
'<authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="~/login.aspx" protection="All" timeout="240" path="/" defaultUrl="~/default.aspx"/>
    </authentication>
    <authorization>
      <deny users="?"/>
    </authorization>'

Answer (score 0):

All `FormsAuthentication.RedirectToLoginPage` does internally is call Response.Redirect. Also, it's bad practice to call `Response.End`. I recommend using a trace tool such as [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) to see what the actual response contains when the method is called. That should shed some light onto what the browser is receiving.

The fact that `Response.Redirect` isn't working is sign of a larger problem. If an HTTP 302 isn't being returned to the client the something in the ASP.net pipeline is getting in the way of the redirect response.